# Entity Framework Core: using navigation properties without foreign key

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have following object model:

```
public class SharingRelation:BaseEntity
{
    public Guid? Code { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class SecondLevelShareEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? SharingCode { get; set; }
    public List<SharingRelation> SharingRelations { get; set; }
}
```

In my database (it may be poor db design but I need to answer this question for research), `SharingRelation` is some sort of dependent entity of `SecondLevelShareEntity` on `Code == SharingCode` values. I can have two entities of type `SecondLevelShareEntity` with same `SharingCode` value. So, for each of them I need to get all related `SharingRelation` objects depending on `Code` and `SharingCode` values. I can do it using SQL and join on this columns. But how can I do it using EF Core and navigation properties (I want to get all dependent entities using `Include()` for example)? When I configure my entities like this

```
public class SharingRelationEntityTypeConfiguration : BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<SharingRelation>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SharingRelation> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);
        builder.HasOne<SecondLevelShareEntity>().WithMany(x => x.SharingRelations).HasForeignKey(x => x.Code)
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.SharingCode);
    }
}
```

EF Core creates foreign key and marks it unique. I am obviously getting an error that that is impossible to have several `SecondLevelShareEntity` with the same `SharingCode`

> System.InvalidOperationException : The instance of entity type 'SecondLevelShareEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{SharingCode: 8a4da9b3-4b8e-4c91-b0e3-e9135adb9c66}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

How can I avoid creation of foreign key, but keep using navigation properties (as far, as I see normal queries with navigations generate simple `JOIN` statements)

**UPDATED** I can provide real data in database. `SecondLevelShareEntity` table looks like this:

```
_id     Name                        SharingCode
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       "firstSecondLevelEnt"       "efcb1c96-0ef1-4bb3-a952-4a6511ab448b"
2       "secondSecondLevelEnt"      "efcb1c96-0ef1-4bb3-a952-4a6511ab448b"
```

And `SharingRelation` table looks like this:

```
_id     Value                       Code
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       "firstSharingRelation"      "efcb1c96-0ef1-4bb3-a952-4a6511ab448b"
2       "secondSharingRelation"     "efcb1c96-0ef1-4bb3-a952-4a6511ab448b"
```

Comment: `Code` and `SharingCode` are not a key in either table?

Comment: You can't. EF (Core) supports only FK relationships (hence navigation properties).

Comment: @Matthew. No, the do not

Comment: You don't necessarily need to have an explicit foreign key *property*. EF has a concept of "shadow properties". However, there must be a foreign key column in the database.

Comment: What do you mean by `have several SecondLevelShareEntity with the same SharingCode`? Share us the expected relationship between `SharingCode`, `SharingRelation` and `SecondLevelShareEntity`

Comment: Each `SecondLevelShareEntity` can have several related `SharingRelation` objects. Relation is based on `SecondLevelShareEntity.SharingCode == SharingRelation. Code`. It seems to be normal one-to-many relation with foreign key `SharingRelation. Code ` and principal key `SecondLevelShareEntity.SharingCode`. But in my situation several `SecondLevelShareEntity` entities can have the same related `SharingRelation` objects.

Comment: It's confused the relationship between `SharingCode` and `List<SharingRelation> SharingRelations`. What is your real table and records?

Comment: @TaoZhou look at updated start post

Comment: How did you create your table? For code-first with your current code, you will got error while inserting the same `efcb1c96-0ef1-4bb3-a952-4a6511ab448b` in `SecondLevelShareEntity`

Comment: @TaoZhou yes. And I want to avoid the error. That is my question. This table was created by raw sql, to demonstrate the issue. And I can use raw sql and `JOIN` to retrieve data I need. But I want to do it using navigation properties (they generate same joins, but i can not use them because when I am setting navigation properties, efcore mark `SharingCode` as unique)

Comment: You need to redesign your relationship. First, if you need `SharingCode` with repeact value, you could not use with `HasPrincipalKey` . Second, why `SharingCode` is `efcb1c96-0ef1-4bb3-a952-4a6511ab448b` instead of `Code` like `firstSharingRelation`?

Comment: @TaoZhou.Sorry for example. Simple mistake. But I want to know, if there is a way to define navigation in such model using EfCore ?